# How to integrate the Plotly dash with the flask app. How to connect them?

Tags: python, flask, plotly

```
    **Python code I used**
```

As you can see in this python code I am trying to redirect the plotly graph template in flask app.
# Step – 1(import necessary library)
from flask import (Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session)
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from flask.helpers import url_for

```
    # Step – 2 (configuring your application)
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = 'xyz'
    
    # step – 3 (creating a dictionary to store information about users)
    user = {"username": "abc", "password": "123"}
    
    # Step – 4 (creating route for login)
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def login():
        if (request.method == 'POST'):
            username = request.form.get('username')
            password = request.form.get('password')
            if username == user['username'] and password == user['password']:
                session['user'] = username
                return redirect('/New_temp')
    
            return "<h1>Wrong username or password</h1>"
    
        return render_template("login.html")
    
    # Step -5(creating route for dashboard and logout)
    @app.route('/New_temp')
    def home():
     if ('user' in session and session['user'] == user['username']):
         return render_template('New_temp.html')
    
    @app.route('/graph', methods=['POST'])
    def graph():
        return render_template('Machine_graph.html')
        pass
        #subprocess.call('Machine_graph.html')
        #return home()
    
        return '<h1>You are not logged in.</h1>'
    
    # Step -7(run the app)
    if __name__== '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your Flask app into Dash object with the 'server' parameter.

```
dash_app = Dash(__name__, server=app, url_base_pathname='/dash/')
```